# Laravel get items by another table's column

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

So, I started learning laravel few days ago and now I have problem with eloquent ORM.

I have 2 tables:

```
Links:
╔════╦═══════╗
║ Id ║ Name  ║
╠════╬═══════╣
║ 1  ║ test  ║
║ 2  ║ test2 ║
╚════╩═══════╝

Likes:
╔════╦═════════╦═══════╦══════════════════╗
║ Id ║ link_id ║ total ║ created_at       ║
╠════╬═════════╬═══════╬══════════════════╣
║ 1  ║ 1       ║ 5     ║ 2014.08.27 11:32 ║
║ 2  ║ 2       ║ 10    ║ 2014.08.29 07:07 ║
╚════╩═════════╩═══════╩══════════════════╝
```

Each day I create new row in `likes` table and then increasing column `total` for each new like. The reason why I doing this, because I need to filter by how many likes has each link today, this week and this month. So, I don't know how to do this in Eloquent ORM. With eager loading looks like it's impossible, because there is 2 different queries, I need something similar to JOINS to use both tables in 1 query.

My current query:

```
$links = Link::with('likes')->paginate(10);
```

Any ideas, how I can do it?

Sorry for my english. Thanks.

**EDIT**

Query in SQL should look similar to:

> SELECT *  FROM links AS ln  LEFT JOIN likes AS lk ON ln.id =
>   lk.link_id WHERE lk.created_at BETWEEN '2014-08-28 09:52:58' and
>   '2014-08-29 09:52:58' ORDER BY lk.total

Comment: [here](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships) may help you

Comment: I already use one to many relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found solution using groupBy, of course now I can't use ->paginate, but I can make it manually, so it's not a big probelm.

I a bit changed `likes` table, now I using COUNT instead SUM, but it should work with both.

```
return self::select('links.*')
            ->addSelect(DB::raw("COUNT(`likes`.`id`) AS `total_likes`"))
            ->join('likes', 'likes.link_id', '=', 'links.id')
            ->whereBetween('likes.created_at', array($start, $end))
            ->groupBy('likes.link_id')
            ->orderBy('total_likes', 'DESC')
            ->take($limit);
```

There is also another way where you can use ->paginate, but I don't think it's a good to use it:

```
$links = Link::select('*')
                ->addSelect(DB::raw("(SELECT COUNT(`likes`.`id`) FROM `likes` WHERE `likes`.`link_id` = `links`.`id` AND `likes`.`created_at` BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end')  AS `total_likes`"))
                ->orderBy('total_likes', 'DESC')
                ->whereHas('likes', function($query) use ($start, $end) {
                    $query->whereBetween('created_at', array($start, $end));
                })->paginate(15);
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if this would work but it is a try;

For days

```
$days = Link::leftJoin('likes', 'likes.id', '=', 'links.id')
->whereBetween('likes.created_at', array(Carbon::now()->subDay(), Carbon::now()))
->orderBy(likes.total)->get();
```

For months

```
$months = Link::leftJoin('likes', 'likes.id', '=', 'links.id')
->whereBetween('likes.created_at', array(Carbon::now()->subMonth(), Carbon::now()))
->orderBy('likes.total')->get();
```

For weeks

```
$months = Link::leftJoin('likes', 'likes.id', '=', 'links.id')
->whereBetween('likes.created_at', array(Carbon::now()->subWeek(), Carbon::now()))
->orderBy('likes.total')->get();
```

Problem with this would be that the id column from Links will be overridden with the value in the likes id column. To overcome this, select the data you want to use within either a select(), or within the get().

Comment: Your example is good if I need only show how many likes the link got today/this week/this month, but I also need to order all links.

Comment: What do you need to order them by as you can just add ->orderBy('column') to the chain before paginating the result?

Comment: By total likes or SUM(likes)

Comment: @creatur Edited the answer to match your SQL.